# True Bypass Looper and Effects Loop

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects

I am thinking of getting myself a looper to control my effect pedals.

Right now some of my pedals are connected via the effects looper and some of them are in the amp front.

My question is, if I buy a looper and connect all pedals through the looper, will I only have to put all pedals through the front of the amp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the effects to be loopable, then they will all be either in the amp input or the effects loop. I would tend to put them all in the effects loop.

To split them out you would need two loopers.

The only exception to this would be if there was a multi-track looper that let you route tracks from different inputs to different outputs. I haven't seen such a thing outside of a full featured DAW.

Comment: So, the standard practice is to not have to split them? (Put all pedals through Effects loop OR amp front)

Comment: it depends on what you need to loop. If you want everything you do to loop, then you need it in the looper, which means you can't split it.

Comment: Without looping, it is easier - you put effects where you want them to sound. It is different adding effects before the preamp and after - we have a question on that here somewhere.

Comment: BTW ... The only pedal I use in front is a Compressor

Comment: In which case, keep the compressor out front (you don't want to recompress every time the signal path loops) and use the looper with all the other effects in the amplifier's effects loop.

Answer (score 1):

The looper I use is stereo (two channel). As these are discrete I guess you could incorporate each channel in each of your effects loops.This will keep everything separate, as it was before. I use it either for keyboards (stereo) or in conjunction with a pedalboard (also stereo), but if yours is for guitar alone, it'll maybe be mono, in which case my answer won't help ! As the good doctor says, any effect you want to loop/record will have to be routed through the looper.

Just realised you haven't bought it yet ! Consider a dual track looper - dearer, but probably more future-proof !